# Saving "new" objects from copies using templated functions c++

Tags: c++, components, variadic-functions, entities, entity-component-system

**My idea:**
I want to be able to create new entities with copies from the components passed in as parameters, also using variadic templated functions for undefined amount of components.

**Reason:** I want a easy way of creating new entities during runtime.

**Problem:** My initial code did not create copies of the components, but was instead using references and saving pointers in an array of components. Also the code required is a bit too complex for me with my current knowledge. Help appreciated.

**Ideal code:**

```
//Creating components
TransformComponent a;
a.SetPosition(50, 50);

RenderComponent b;
b.SetColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

//Creating entities
EntityHandle entity1 = CreateEntity(a, b, ...); //Undefined amount of components

//Assign new values
a.SetPosition(100,100);
b.SetColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
EntityHandle entity2 = CreateEntity(a, b, ...); 
//New entity has a copy of the same components
//used when creating the first entity, 
//without changing the values of the first entity
```

**My attempt so far:** (works when passing in component references)

```
TransformComponent tTest;
tTest.transform.SetPosition(200.f, 200.f);
RenderComponent rTest;
rTest.texture = &texture;

ecs.CreateEntity(&tTest, &rTest);

//Creating an entity with undefined number of arguments
template <class... Component>
EntityHandle CreateEntity(Component*... componets)
{
    EntityHandle newEntity = CreateEntity();
    AddComponent(newEntity, componets...);
    return newEntity;
}

void DestroyEntity(EntityHandle handle);

//component methods

template<class Component, class... Args>
void AddComponent(EntityHandle handle, Component* component, Args*... args)
{
    AddComponent(handle, component);
    AddComponent(handle, args...);
}

template<class Component>
void AddComponent(EntityHandle handle, Component* component)
{
    AddComponentInternal(handle, ECSComponent<Component>::familyID, (BaseECSComponent*)component);
}
```

Im using a Entity-Component-System system, and EntityHandle is an ID reference to an entity.

CreateEntity returns the id to an object. At first i was calling AddComponent(entityHandle, &component) to add new components (they are saved as pointers in my ECS system) but that became annoying when i started creating objects in runtime and when i wanted to create alot of objects in a loop.

**Possible solution?:**

Create new entites with the "new" keyword:

```
EntityHandle entity = CreateEntity(new TransformComponent(position), new RenderComponent(color));
```

This however requires all of my struct components to have constructors that sets all of its values.

**EDIT:**
I might be completely wrong here but i think what im asking for is a way to "convert" a stack object to a heap object, and that is presumably impossible?

Comment: What do you mean by *"New entity has the new values of the same components"*? In what sense does it "have" them? How does it use those components? In the "Ideal code" example, it would help if you show how `entity1` and `entity2` are expected to be used, in a way that the "value of components" matters.

Comment: You might be looking for something like `void AddComponent(EntityHandle handle, Component* component) { AddComponentInternal(..., new Component(*component));}`